# How to configure DCOM configuration for Export To Excel?

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, dcom

I am implementing Export To Excel functionality in one of my asp.net application. I have two servers(QA and Development). In Development server it works fine but in QA server i am getting below error.

```
    An exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred and was 
caught. Source:mscorlib;Message:Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The 
server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect.  Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x8000401A).;Target:System.MarshalByRefObject AllocateUninitializedObject(System.RuntimeType);StackTrace:   at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)     at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)     at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)     at 
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& 
bNeedSecurityCheck)     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)     at 
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)     at 
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)     at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)     at XXXXXXXXXXXXX  Method - XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have configured same thing in both servers but still QA server not working properly. What should i do next? Any idea...??

Answer (score 0):

Is Excel 2000 installed on your QA server ? At least it wasn't able to startup the automation...

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292491/en-us

> Excel.Application version-independent PROGID and the
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} CLSID. COM related registry
>   entries for Excel 2000 include the following:
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Application\CLSID Default Value:
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32
>
> Default Value: C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office\EXCEL.EXE /automation By
>   following the registry keys from the PROGID to the CLSID, COM can
>   learn where the Excel executable file is installed and start it for
>   Automation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where the identity was lost in between the session and I had to give the credentials again to fix it temporarily. While investigating it, I came across an article that suggested granting the domain account that is used as identity with 'Logon as a Batch job' privilege as the identity would be lost when the AD performs an update if the privilege is not granted.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/312497/prb-com-application-under-domain-account-fails-intermittently

https://www.brooksnet.com/faq/granting-logon-as-batch-privilege